Swift - mutate struct after downcast
This is the abstraction of my code:
protocol MyProtocol {
    var value1: Int {get set}
    var value2: Int {get set}
}

struct MyStruct: MyProtocol {
    var value1: Int = 1
    var value2: Int = 2
    var value3: Int = 3
}

struct MyWrapper {
    var wrapped: MyProtocol
}

var myWrappedStruct = MyWrapper(wrapped: MyStruct())

I know for certain what my wrapper is holding  therefore I can cast the abstract protocol type to a MyStruct. But if I try to change any of the values, I get an compile time error:
(myWrappedStruct.wrapped as! MyStruct).value3 += 1 // Left side of mutating operator has immutable type 'Int'

When I change MyStruct to be a class instead it works. So, obviously, when downcasting a struct an immutable copy is being created for read only access.
How can I mutate the properties of a struct, when the actual type is hidden by a protocol?

Protocols are usually more about expressing behaviour and semantics, not just describing meaningless bags full of properties. The right way to model this is with a method on the protocol which the struct implements to mutate as necessary

Problem is: I want to change the one value which is not a protocol requirement. In my original code I was using a base class instead of a protocol and the MyStruct was a subclass of that class. But after reading the Apple document on when to use structs/classes I got the impression that my objects fall into the category where using structs is recommended. It became my understanding that protocols are the way to define common functionality so you can get a behaviour similar to class inheritance, which otherwise would not be possible with structs.

The common factor between structs+protocols and classes+inheritance is polymorphism: the ability to invoke a method, whose concrete implementation is automatically decided based on the object's type. The methods are usually meant to describe goals and behaviours, not concrete implementation details like instance variable storage. In either case, it's generally an anti-pattern to down-cast from the super type (the protocol or super class) to the subtype. It's hard to recommend an alternative without knowing exactly what you're trying to do, though. What's your protocol? What's the property?

I am sure that as soon as I describe a larger scope of my problem someone will point fingers and claim it to be an A/B problem: Are classes or structs better suited for my use case. But ok: The goal is to develop a music sequencer. An array holds MIDI-events which are sorted by their timestamp. The actual events can be very different things, but their common property - the timestamp - must be accessible. So I am using a wrapping opject, that holds the timestamp, and an .event of Type MyProtocol.

(cont.) As every event happens exactly one time at a specific place in time It seems reasonable to consider each event as a unique object, which to me seems to be an indicator to favour structs. At some time the user might want to copy/paste some events to a different place and edit some of its properties. When I would do this with a class I would have to come up with a copying mechanism that creates a new instance with the same values - which feels like coding against the reference-based nature of classes...

(cont.) On the other hand, to edit properties of an event I need to downcast it, as for example musical notes can alter their pitches, while an event controlling the volume does not have a pitch property. When downcasting a class this is simple. With structs it is - as I am finding out now - not.

"each event as a unique object, which to me seems to be an indicator to favour structs" I'd say that reasoning is exactly backwards. Each event is a real thing — an actual individual musical signal. That's a class. Structs are for temporary messages; classes are for things that correspond to stable factual externalities. So use a class, stop beating yourself up, and move on.

A struct is a value type. It is not mutable.
It is possible to create the illusion of "mutating" a struct, but only if the struct is referred to through a var variable. What really happens in that situation is that a new struct is created and copied into the var variable — which is why the variable must be a var.
Thus, (myWrappedStruct.wrapped as! MyStruct) is not a reference pointing at the the wrapped struct; it is effectively a different struct, and is therefore treated as immutable — because structs are immutable.
So, if you want to "mutate" your wrapped struct, you have to copy it out into a var variable, mutate the variable, and copy it back in:
var myWrappedStruct = MyWrapper(wrapped: MyStruct())
var contents = myWrappedStruct.wrapped as! MyStruct
contents.value3 += 1
myWrappedStruct.wrapped = contents

This really is just another instance of the familiar phenomenon where a struct passed to a function cannot be mutated by that function:
struct S {
    var p: Int = 0
}

func g(_ theStruct: S) {
    theStruct.p += 1 // left side of mutating operator isn't mutable...
}

A class, on the other hand, is a reference type, so none of that applies; you can point (refer) to and mutate the class instance in place.

In a function I can pass the struct as an inout parameter, then I can mutate it inside the function body. I am hoping there is some similar solution when downcasting.

There is, but think about it: how are you going to make a function with an inout parameter that can accommodate any change to any property? I mean, really? I mean, by the time you've set all that up, it will have been simpler just to use the three-line solution I've shown you. It's just the price of using structs.

And no matter what you do, you will just be pushing same problem further and further down the pipeline. Someone has to pull out a copy into a var ref, "mutate" that, and set the copy back in. Even Superman has to put on his pants one leg at a time.
